# Access foreign key image in template

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    # some fields

class CarPhotos(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='somewhere')
    car = models.ForeignKey(Car)
```

in views.py:

```
def car_list(request):
    cars = Car.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'borsa/car_list.html', {'cars': cars})
```

in car_list.html:

```
 {% for car in cars %}
    <a href="car/{{ car.pk }}/view/">
      <img class="media-object tmbpic" src="{{ car.carphotos_set.all.0.image.url }}" alt="kola">
    </a>
```

The first method I've used was to use inline formsets but I had no clue how to access the images. Can you please point me in the right direction of how to access images according to Car objects ? I mean every Car must have a couple of images and I need to display only the first one in list view, but then I need to display all of them in Detail view.

Comment: That seems to be exactly what you've done. What, precisely, is the problem?

Comment: And I don't know what any of that has to do with formsets - you aren't using them here, and I can't imagine why they'd be relevant.

Comment: The problem is I am not able to access all the images, as I am uploading multiple images per instance. I've mentioned that I've used inline formsets to add multiple images in admin area. I am completely confused as I have altered my code a few times.

Answer (score 0):

To display all of them, you need to do something like:

```
{% for car in cars %}
    {% for photo in car.carphotos_set.all %}
       <img src="{{ photo.image.url }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

So loop through the cars, then nest-loop through the images per car.